# how do i print out print out vector<string> when i get a 'compilr.com/rayd360/test-songst'

Tags: c++, vector

Complete program here for clarification: compilr.com/rayd360/test-songs

```
struct Album {
  string title;
  string year;
  string track;
  vector<string> tracks;
  vector<string>::iterator trk;
}MyAlbums[40];

cout << "\n list of songs: \n";
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  cout << *MyAlbums[i].trk << "\n";
}
```

gives me: "bash: line 1:   232 Segmentation fault      "

I am needing to pass the list of tracks to a function that sorts them alphabetically then prints them out.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to print? Is it `title`, `year`, or `track`?

Comment: I guess he's talking about print `trk` which is iterator pointing to tracks. so he wants to print tracks.

Answer (score 1):

The line in the for loop dereferences the iterator returned by `MyAlbums[i].trk`. Since the iterator isn't assigned to anything (its internal pointer isn't pointing to anything) dereferencing it is Undefined Behavior. This can also cause a segmentation fault since your looking into memory that isn't owned by you.

To fix this I think you should remove the iterator from your class. Instead, use one inside your loop:

```
auto begin = MyAlbums.tracks.begin(),
     end   = MyAlbums.tracks.end();

for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Album {
string title;
string year;
string track;


}MyAlbums[40];
vector<Album> tracks;
vector<Album>::iterator trk=tracks.begin();
cout << "\n list of songs: \n";
for(trk;trk!=tracks.end();++trk){
cout << *trk.title << "\n";
```

Assuming that you have already populated the MyAlbums.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1) MyAlbums[i].trk is not initialized

2) While iterating through containers, ensure not to access container with invalid index.

(Ex: for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) is not safe in this context).

```
// C++11
for ( auto track : MyAlbums.tracks )
{
       cout << track << "\n";
}  

// If not C++11
for (vector<string>::Iterator trackItr = MyAlbums.begin(); 
     trackItr != MyAlbums.end(); ++trackItr)
{
     cout << *trackItr << "\n";
}
```